# how to get ATR value or number from NFCTagReaderSession NFCISO7816Tag tag in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I am able to connect to the card using NFCTagReaderSession and NFCISO7816Tag tag but i can't get ATR number after connection and it shows zero bytes in historicalBytes, while in android we are able to get some number in historicalBytes for same type of cards

One more filed we have NFCISO7816Tag "identifier" but it is getting different number for same type of card.

```
 print("iso7816Tag historical bytes \(iso7816Tag.historicalBytes)")

 print("iso7816Tag identifier \(iso7816Tag.identifier)")
```

We want same number or value for same type of card that can be used for ATR validation in our code.

Please suggest to get an ATR number or value for same type of cards.

Comment: is there procedure to get an ATR number or value

Comment: As of now for iso7816Tag, only few parameters are exposed. initialSelectedAID, identifier, historicalBytes, applicationData, proprietaryApplicationDataCoding. Even I am trying to access SAK. But it always returns 0